# How to prevent from stacking views in a custom segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I coded a custom segue emulating a "Push Left". I takes screenshots of the 2 views, animates them from right to left, then present the destination view and remove the overlaying screenshots. I'm afraid that this ultimately results in stacking views on top of one another, which should be avoided in this case. I can't figure out how to properly dismiss the underlaying view once the animation is completed. I tried to use `navigationController?.pushViewController` instead of `present` but my attempts were not successful. How could I solve this issue ?

My custom segue :

```
class SeguePushLeft: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        self.source.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.destination.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        let slideViewOut = UIImageView(image: source.view.capture()!)
        let slideViewIn = UIImageView(image: destination.view.capture()!)

        let screenWidth = source.view.frame.size.width

        self.source.view.addSubview(slideViewIn)
        self.source.view.addSubview(slideViewOut)

        slideViewIn.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: screenWidth, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {

                        slideViewIn.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                        slideViewOut.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -screenWidth, y: 0)

        }, completion: { finished in

            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                (self.source as UIViewController).present((self.destination as UIViewController), animated: false, completion: {

                    self.source.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    self.destination.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                    slideViewIn.removeFromSuperview()
                    slideViewOut.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Please forgive my previous too-hasty answer. I'm entering another rather than editing the first, because of all the comments that now blot the first.]

The problem is simple: you're doing this wrong. What you wish to do is a `present` transition, but with a custom animation. That's perfectly viable, and you can certainly do it with a custom segue, but the way you're doing it is not how you do that. You do it with a *custom transition animation*. There is a fixed way of implementing that, and it isn't how you're going about things. You need to read up on how to write a custom transition animation for a presentation transition and you'll be all set.

Comment: I happen to have a complete example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch06p325customSegue/CustomSegue/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for your answer & example. So if I understand well you suggest to implement a custom _Animator_ for an existing transition ? Just so that I understand better your code, what should your custom animation look like in that case ? I'm confused with the ```r1``` / ```r2``` representation. Now even coding a custom animator for a modal presentation, this presentation will still result in a vertical stack of VCs right ? Could I use another existing type of transition instead, along with a custom animator, that would prevent from stacking VCs vertically ? Which one to you ? How exactly ? Thanks

Comment: If you do a fullscreen presentation, there is no "vertical stack of VCs"; the new view controller view comes in and covers the old view controller view, which is removed. That has nothing to do with the custom transition animation, which is responsible for how the animation itself _looks_ during the transition. Run my example and see.